# Automatic Flash updates don't work

Tags: updates, flash-player

Normally when Flash updates are available, the updater opens after system boot, and it's a small wizard where you can just click "install", accept an agreement, and everything happens automatically.

Last 2 Flash updates, the button said "download" instead, and I had to go to the Adobe website, download and save the package, and run it.

Why, if it was previously possible without browser, does Adobe force me to go to the website now? First time I even forgot to uncheck that stupid Mcafee thing.

I am on Windows 7 x64 and a friend happens to have had the same issue (just to say it's no coincidence). My main browser is Firefox. Does anyone have the same problem? Is there a solution?

Edit: I've tried the [knowledge base article](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/administration-configure-auto-update-notification.html) and my settings are:

```
AutoUpdateDisable=0
SilentAutoUpdateEnable=1
```

These settings do not make the problem disappear.

Comment: I searched with google for [adobe flash automatic update] and this was the first hit:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/administration-configure-auto-update-notification.html

Have you read this?

Comment: -1: Your question does not show research effort; see the comment by @PeterJenkins.

Comment: @DragonLord My question was about the auto-update **wizard** that appears on boot, not downloading it anymore. They are two different topics.

Comment: 2 downvotes because I didn't try something first that in the end, didn't work for me anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is well answered by adobe here:

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/administration-configure-auto-update-notification.html

You need to enable the automatic update notification, and you need to open a webpage that uses flash. Since this page loads flash to display the settings, it's a good example:

http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager05.html

Comment: My settings are as described. The silent update is enabled, as well as auto-update. How come these appear to be disregarded?

Comment: Well, my past experience of Windows is that these kinds of things get broken easily. You could try manually updating, then waiting for an update, then using flash and seeing if you get prompted or not.

Comment: Frankly it's this kind of hassle that drove me to using Chrome which has flash built in and always auto updates without prompting.

Comment: I would use chrome, hadn't it been for me being so used to firefox. It just feels better to me. I know chrome is better in many aspects, but I can't let go of firefox's look and feel. I know where everything is, if I need to change a setting or do other stuff. I just don't know why flash would suddenly force me to go to a website to download an update manually...